# Is this MARIE instruction set even possible?

Tags: assembly, instruction-set, marie

I was given the following MARIE instruction set and told to output what the symbol table was for the first pass, and the result in the AC. The problem is, I don't even think this is possible:

```
Hex
Address     Label     Instruction

100         Start,    LOAD A
101                   ADD B
102                   STORE D
103                   CLEAR
104                   OUTPUT
105                   ADDI D
106                   STORE B
107                   HALT
108         A,        HEX 00FC
```

I just don't see how we can `ADD B` when the label isn't declared below, and the fact that to `ADDI D`, we'd need to have the actual value stored in B. Otherwise the assembler will do the first pass, not find a label associated for B after the instructions, and then keep looping trying to add B to the AC, store it in D, add the pointer associated with D to the AC, and going back to store B.

I'd appreciate any info or pointers (no pun intended) on what I may be missing here.

Comment: this is node an instruction set, it's a piece of code. You're right when you say this code will not assemble without an error, but I think this is not the question here. in 2 step assemblers, the first pass often only collects all label-address relations, wouldn't find B and D, and complain about this in the 2nd pass, or at the latest when trying to link